# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (Shopping cart with javascript project)

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

so I'm working at shopping cart with Javascript and I'm getting this error:

**`store.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at updateCartTotal`**

This is the code:

```
var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
console.log(removeCartItemButtons)
for (var i =0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var buttonClicked = event.target
        buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
        updateCartTotal()
    })
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity.input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value()
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }    
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total
}
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with the data provided do the following

```js
//fix the selector
cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity.input')[0]
//to this
cartRow.querySelectorAll('input.cart-quantity')[0];

//change this
var quantity = quantityElement.value()
//to this
var quantity = quantityElement.value
```